# comparing lists of tuples

Tags: python

I have the following code, comparing two lists that contains equally structured tuples:

```py
list_one = [('id_01','aaa','bbb'), ('id_02','aaa','bbb'), ('id_03','aaa','bbb'), ('id_04','aab','bbc')]
list_two = [('id_01','aaa','bbb'), ('id_02','aaa','bbb'), ('id_03','aad','bbd')]

for tupl in list_one:
    for tup in list_two:
        if tupl[0] == tup[0] and (tupl[1] != tup[1] or tupl[2] != tup[2]):
                print("There is a difference on "+
                      "{} between the two lists".format(tup[0]))
```

this code would print
`There is a difference on id_03 between the two lists`
which is the expected result.
But I wonder if there is a better way to achieve the same result, maybe whitout iterating through `list_two` for every item of `list_one`, but any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If `id_03` were the same in both lists what output would you expect?

Comment: Hi @Peilonrayz I understand it would be a good idea including this validation, but for my scope, I'm only concerned about the differences, i.e. this validation not returning anything would mean that everything is ok.

Comment: Are the lists in order by id?  That is, the tuple with id_01 is before the tuple with id_02, etc.  The sample data has them in order; is that always the case?

Comment: No @RootTwo, and the real IDS are strings, like, "SOMETHING_OTHER_SOMETHING", without any kind of ordinance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be better off [using `set`](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/functions#set). It provides features like set difference by itself, thereby reducing a lot of work at your end:

```
set_one = set([('id_01','aaa','bbb'), ('id_02','aaa','bbb'), ('id_03','aaa','bbb'), ('id_04','aab','bbc')])
set_two = set([('id_01','aaa','bbb'), ('id_02','aaa','bbb'), ('id_03','aad','bbd')])
for difference in (set_two - set_one):
    print(f"There is a difference on {difference[0]} between the two lists")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use a dictionary instead of a list. The `id_01` in your case would be the key for each dictionary and the other items can be contained in a list.

Like this (same for dict_two)

```
dict_one = {
    'id_01': ['aaa', 'bbb'],
    'id_02': ['aaa', 'bbb'],
}
```

then you can iterate over the keys

```
for k in dict_one.keys():
    if dict_one[k][0] != dict_two[k][0] or dict_one[k][1] != dict_two[k][1]:
       print("there is a diff....")
```

Comment: This doesn't work the same as the OP's

Comment: It does what was asked for `a better way to achieve the same result, maybe whitout iterating through list_two for every item of list_one,` . What do you think is missing in my suggestion?  The data structure used by OP seems inappropriate for what they want to do with it, don't you agree?

Comment: it'd raise an error for key id_04

Comment: @hjpotter92 correct. I assumed too much